# Accessing List inside A class

Tags: c#

Why can't I add values to the list inside a created class? ex. I write carType_list.add

```
class Vehicles
{
    List<string> carType_list = new List<string>();
    List<string> carModel_list = new List<string>();
    List<int> seatCapacity_list = new List<int>();
    List<string> mileageLimit_list = new List<string>();
    List<double> ratings_list = new List<double>();
    List<double> rentPrice_list = new List<double>();
}
```

Comment: (1) Because all those fields are private and (2) Because even if they were public, you have to spell the `Add()` method with a capital A.

Comment: For performing such operations, you have to use a constructor or some function. You can simply do that in the class. The class can only contain `methods` and `fields`. I think there is an option for static block (which can be used to initialize like this).

Comment: You really should do some C# trainings before asking such questions on SO.

Comment: I fixed it combining all of your answers guys. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I first updated the accessibility of the lists into public then used a public constructor

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Use Constructor

A better way to initialize all `class` variables is to use a constructor. The constructor is like a method but it is called when an `object` of that `class` is created.
You can do like:

```
class Vehicles
{
    List<string> carType_list = new List<string>();
    // ... fields
    
    // constructor
    Vehicle(){
        carType_list.Add("4 wheeler");
    }
    // ... constructors or functions
    // add car or type methods, etc.
}
```

#### A better way (Getters and Setters)

Currently, the fields are not `public`, so they can't be accessed outside the class. It is highly encouraged to use the `getter`s and `setter`s instead of making them `public` if you want to update the field outside the class, like:

```
class Vehicles
{
    // declare fields with get, set
    public List<string> carType_list{ get; set; }
    // ... fields
    
    public constructor(){
        carType_list = new List<string>(); // initilize
        carType_list.Add("4 wheeler"); // add value
    }
    // ... constructors or functions
    // add methods or some
}
```

### Static Constructor

- Only static fields can be initizlied this way.

If the `class` has some `static` attributes that need to be initiated without instantiating `class`. You can use [static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) for that.

```
class Vehicles
{
    static List<string> carType_list = new List<string>();
    // ... fields
    
    // static constructor
    static Vehicle(){
        carType_list.Add("4 wheeler");
    }
    // ... constructors or functions
}
```

Comment: That answer is not really correct despite having been accepted. There are no static fields in the class shown in the question, therefore no static constructor is required. Calling `Add()` from the outside still won't work if the fields are still private.

Comment: The `static` constructor will not help if the fields are not `static`. But the first part of using the constructor is helpful for initializing value. And in my opinion, the asker does not want to initialize them from outside of the class. (That's why he has not declared them `public`).

Comment: @ewerspej I have also updated the instructions for getters and setters. I hope the answer is satisfied now.

Comment: It wasn't specified from where items should be added, so you're basing your proposal purely on an assumption. With private fields, items could still be added from within methods of that same class.

Comment: It should still be `Add()` with a capital "A".

Comment: My bad! Mistyped that.  Updated the question.

Comment: Update : I made the lists public and used a public constructor also, that fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need to make the class and its members public in order to manipulate it from the outside:

```cs
public class Vehicles
{
    public List<string> carType_list = new List<string>();
    public List<string> carModel_list = new List<string>();
    public List<int> seatCapacity_list = new List<int>();
    public List<string> mileageLimit_list = new List<string>();
    public List<double> ratings_list = new List<double>();
    public List<double> rentPrice_list = new List<double>();
}
```

Then you can call `Add()` on each of the lists from the outside. If the fields remain private, you would only be able to populate the lists from within your class, e.g. the Constructor or any non-static class method.

Ideally, you would move the initialization to the Constructor and then add values from anywhere else, inside or outside of your class, depending on your use cases.

Comment: The title says "Accessing List **Inside** Class"

Comment: Then there wouldn't have been any problem, private fields are always accessible from within their own class.

Comment: Basically, the description of the question says, he wants to write some statements like `add` in the class like a declaration. But it gives the error.

Comment: Yes and that can be either done inside a constructor, a method or from the outside. None of which was specified explicitly. I'm not saying your answer is wrong, it's just making assumptions based on rather little information.

Comment: My bad, for the little information provided, Ill be sure to be precise next time. Problem fixed by making the fields into public and used a public constructor. Thank you guys.